# Meteor Counts in Router Level Subscription

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze

I have a list that subscribes to `posts` publication with a `limit`.

**Publication**

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(options) {
  check(options, {
    sort: Object,
    limit: Number
  });

  var posts = Posts.find({}, options);

  return posts;
});
```

within the list, I have items under each

**list.html**

```
{{#each posts}}
  {{> postItem}}
{{/each}}
```

within each `postItem`, I would like to count its comment number.

I believe the code for above would be

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
   commentsCount: function () {
    return Comments.find({postId: this._id }).count();
   }
});
```

The problem with this is that I would have to publish all of comments inside `posts` publication which would really be inefficient.

I would like to make a publication where I could subscribe to it within Template level for each `postItems` and just return the resulting `Counts` I tried `tmeasday:publish-counts` but I did not figure out how to make it work in my case, or even if it would be used in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Keep track number of comment in the `Posts` collection itself.

Each time new Comment inserted, update the counter:

```
Posts.update(
 { _id: String },
 { $inc: { commentsCount: 1 } }
)
```

This way you doesn't need to subscribe `Comments` just to get the count, which will involve multiple round trip to server.

**Option 2**: Use `Meteor.methods` and `Meteor.call` to return the number of comment for each Posts. Multiple round trip to server will occur.

**Option 3**: Use [aggregation](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/) to [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and count no of comment on server and map it back to Posts on client.

**Option 4**: [Reactive joins](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/)

I strongly recommend option #1 for performance and reactivity.

Comment: I use option 1 right now. If that is recommended, I will keep it that way. Thank you :)